# How to add timestamp to the existing mysql table

Tags: mysql, datetime, laravel, timestamp

I am updatng my application from standard php into laravel and i am creating two new field in each of my table which is created_at and updated_at.

The problem is both field has being set as null for the existing data. How to make a query to set the created_at and updated_at to the current date time??

Comment: Do you want to do it trought a migration or doesn't mind?

Comment: i've found the answer by using this query

UPDATE mytable SET created_at = '2014-05-26 17:35:10';

Comment: You should create a migration, and add the columns there. Set the default to something like `new DateTime()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (UPDATE query). You can use a function, to get same NOW() for both columns created_at and updated_at.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c204e9/1

```
UPDATE table_name SET created_at = NOW(), updated_at=NOW() WHERE created_at IS NULL AND updated_at IS NULL
```

This only works if both columns are null.

Comment: Hello, for archive purpose please put the relevant code in your answer, to avoid broken links in future ;)